# HDRP Terrain Missing in VR After Build

Tags: unity-game-engine, build, terrain, unity3d-terrain

I'm currently working on a VR project in Unity HDRP which can be played in Oculus Quest 2. I have multiple scenes and one of the scenes has a map which is from Unity's free assets.

Here's the link to the assets:

https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/3d/environments/unity-terrain-hdrp-demo-scene-213198

The game is working well. As I tested it in the Unity Editor 2022.2.15f1, the game runs well in VR, no missing assets or critical errors or else, just some minor bugs.

[pic: there's the terrain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9QtO.jpg)

When I tried to build the game in Windows platform, the build was a success. But, when I tried it on my VR, that free asset terrain went missing.

[pic: the terrain is gone what](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pciG.jpg)

How can I solve this issue? Or is the free asset broken so I need to use another asset and start over again only for that scene?

Thanks in advance.

[pic: setup1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyzms.jpg)

[pic: setup2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qS22Q.jpg)

[pic: setup3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBpkT.jpg)

[pic: setup4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqTxH.jpg)

Comment: Update: no improvements yet

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you with a Terrain from other Asset. And I finally found the problem. I don't know if it will be your case, but you could try. I hope it helps you. Greetings.

In the Terrain Settings. You have to disable de option Draw Instanced.

[image: Terrain Settings Configuration Screen]